# Wordpress query by multiple metaboxes and order by date

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

So here is my query:

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'Event',
    'posts_per_page' => 1000,
    'meta_key' => 'event_informations_show_on_the_homepage',
    'meta_value' => 'Show on the homepage',
    'meta_compare' => '==',
    'meta_key' => 'event_informations_date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I want to select all posts that have the metabox `event_informations_show_on_the_homepage` and the value of the metabox `event_informations_show_on_the_homepage` and order by the date metabox which is stored as a timestamp and is called `event_informations_date`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are overwriting the key `meta_key` in your `$args` array.

Comment: But I need two meta_keys how should I do it?

Comment: You can't easily. You'll need to either extend [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for your use-case or [filter it](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_orderby) (or both). It might be easier to directly query the database for your use-case even, see [`wpdb`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).

Comment: I have no idea how to this with `wpdb` never use it can you help me out?

Comment: I think it's easiest with the [`posts_orderby` filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_orderby). You can change the `ORDER BY` clause manually which is what you're looking for because the array syntax for parameters does not allow you to specify a different `meta_key` for ordering than comparing.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully I'm not barking up the wrong tree here.

You can use the key '**meta_query**' to filter posts by multiple meta keys like so:

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'Event',
    'posts_per_page' => 1000,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
                'key' => 'event_informations_show_on_the_homepage',
                'value' => 'yes',
        ),
        array(
                'key' => 'event_informations_date',
                'value' => 'yes',
        )
     )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

What WordPress is doing here is creating multiple wheres against the same column by using innerjoins on the same table, each time using a different alias. It's pretty cool & is probably the fastest way to query like that.

For more information see here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

Hope this helps :)

Comment: You ain't barking up the wrong tree - `meta_query` is the way to go. +1.

Comment: If you have `orderby meta_value_num`, I believe you're also going to need a `meta_key=keyname` in there somewhere.